# Python Session update cookies

Tags: python, python-3.x, session, cookies, session-cookies

**Update: I let-rally tried 12 suggested solutions but nothing worked at all.**
Is my question missing any details? The suggested answer doesn't solve the problem

In python I wrote:

```
print(s.cookies.get_dict())
```

where s is my session, the output is:

```
{'lubl': 'https%3A%2F%2Fopenworld.com%2Fconfirm', 'rishum': 'SHjshd2398-'}
```

Now my question is how can I edit rishum cookie such that I want to append 'test' next to it (or to make things simple replace it by 'test')?

For example, I want:

```
'rishum': 'SHjshd2398-test'
```

---

**Note: as someone suggested I tried the following but didn't work:**

```
print(s.cookies.get_dict())
s.cookies.get_dict()['rishum'] = 'test'
print(s.cookies.get_dict())
```

output before and after is:

{'lubl': 'confirm', 'rishum': 'SUqsadkjn239s8n-', 'PHPSESSID': 'nfdskjfn3k42342', 'authchallenge': 'asjkdnjnkj34'}

{'rishum': 'SUqsadkjn239s8n-', 'lubl': 'confirm', 'PHPSESSID': 'nfdskjfn3k42342', 'authchallenge': 'asjkdnjnkj34'}

Note the order has changed.

Comment: I tried everything in the internet but Nothing worked

Comment: In public I have: s = Session()

Answer (score 1):

The way i understood from your question, s is json file that equals to

```
s = {'lubl': 'https%3A%2F%2Fopenworld.com%2Fconfirm', 'rishum': 'SHjshd2398-'}
```

than if you want to add 'test' to the end of 'rishum', you need to do the following

```
s['rishum'] = s['rishum'] + 'test'
```

and than

```
print(s)
```

I believe your mistake was that you called function twice, that's why you saw same answer.

Comment: What did I call twice? I printed before and after but no change was made. Plus s isn't json as I mentioned s=session()

Answer (score 1):

In that case, you first need to delete your cookie and than create a new one,
i would do it this way:

```
print(s.cookies.get_dict())

my_cookie = s.cookies.get_dict()['rishum'] + 'test' 
s.cookies.set('rishum', None)
s.cookies.set('rishum', my_cookie)

print(s.cookies.get_dict())
```